# How does RVM detect when you've changed directories?

Tags: rvm, internals

One thing that RVM can do is notice when you've changed directories, look for an `.rvmrc`, and change your current Ruby version and gemset according to that file's contents. It makes this change as soon as you change into that directory and outputs a message accordingly.

**How does it detect a change in the current working directory?** I can imagine an extremely crude way of doing this: run a daemon that runs as the current user and keeps checking the results of `pwd`. But I'm sure that's not what it does.

Another approach might be to alias `cd` to change directories but also check for an `.rvmrc` and change gemsets if so instructed.

Is there a Unix system hook for changing directories, or is there some other trick that RVM is using?

Comment: Since pwd is per-process, not per-user, i don't think the daemon would work.

Comment: @TomAnderson Absolutely right. I was confused about the concept. :)

Comment: Incidentally, I'm now using chruby, and have [customized its directory-monitoring behavior to suit my usage in zsh](http://nathanmlong.com/2015/01/optimizing-chruby-for-zsh/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> How does [RVM] detect a change in the current working directory?

This entirely depends on the shell and even shell version. The simplest method for accomplishing this is, as was suggested, overriding `cd` by defining a function of the same name. Be sure to call the built in `cd` function or you will cause either *very* nasty or *very* amusing side effects (depending on perspective).

```
cd() {
  builtin cd $*
  echo "Changed directories from '${OLDPWD}' to '${PWD}'."
}
```

By placing this in a text source file and sourcing the file you can load this custom `cd` functionality into the session sourcing the file.

```
wayneeseguin$ cd /tmp
Changed directories from '/home/wayneeseguin' to '/tmp'.
```

If you would like this to always be in effect for interactive shells in your user account either place the function definition into `~/.bash_profile`. Alternatively you can source the text file in which you stored the function in from `~/.bash_profile`. You can [read more about Bash startup files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the Bash manual.

[The Ruby enVironment Manager (RVM)](https://rvm.io) is written in and targeted mainly for the [Bash shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). RVM will work in the [ZSH shell](http://www.zsh.org/) which allows you to add function calls to after a `cd` action. This is by far the best way to approach solving this task. So, if your shell allows for it, by all means use this method. RVM does.

For an extensive example you can [look at RVM's cd functionality on GitHub](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/cd#L7-86).

RVM utilizes this functionality for loading [per-project (directory, really) `.rvmrc` files](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/#project) as well as providing users with the ability to configure various hooks. You can read more about [RVM's hooks on the documentation website](https://rvm.io/workflow/hooks).

Answer (score 4):

When you install RVM you have to add:

```
[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

to your shell config (usually `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`).

This loads RVM when you start a shell which then overrides your `cd` command and checks for `.rvmrc`s as you move around.  See the contents of `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/cd` for more details.

Comment: The RVM install for me did this automatically, to .bash_profile