# RVM after_cd Hook

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to use the [RVM hooks](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/hooks) to run a command after I `cd` into a directory with my rails app.

The contents of my `~/.rvm/hooks/after_cd` is:

```
echo "Now using $rvm_ruby_string"
```

The contents of my `~/.rvm/hooks/after_use` is:

```
echo "Now using $rvm_ruby_string"
```

When I do `$rmv use 1.9.2` I see my echo, but when I `cd` into the rails root directory for my app I don't get any echo.

Am I using the `after_cd` hook wrong?

`$rvm -v` says:

```
rvm 1.0.8 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Comment: When I check my own `rvm --version`, it says `1.8.0`. Maybe upgrading to a newer RVM will help?

Comment: 1.8.5 is the most current and stable.

Comment: @SooDesuNe Work for me though

Answer (score 4):

First you need to understand how rvm overwrite your system's default cd command.

Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605277/how-does-rvm-detect-when-youve-changed-directories) explains this well.

In short, rvm defines a function like this in .rvm/script/cd

```
cd(){
  builtin cd $*                    #run system cd
  source after_cd_hooks            #run hook scripts
}
```

And you can find this line if you look into how this cd() defined.

`__rvm_project_rvmrc && __rvm_after_cd || true`

`__rvm_project_rvmrc` is the function to check if .rvmrc exists in the directory you change into.

**So the hook scripts will only be sourced when .rvmrc exists in your project root.**

So create your .rvmrc and try the cd again. Good Luck!

```
> /path/to/app/root/.rvmrc
cd /path/to/app/root
```

My rvm version:

```
rvm -v

rvm 1.23.14 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```