# What tool runs during a "cd" and checks the .ruby_version file?

Tags: ruby, shell, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, environment

I've installed a bunch of tools related to ruby recently.  Macports ruby19 (then uninstalled per advice here on SO), then installed RVM and ruby-1.9.3-p.

Now I notice that I get a message when I `cd` or even `\cd` into a directory with a .ruby-version file that I do not have the matching version of ruby installed.   And it's driving me crazy: what tool is performing this check?

The only thing that I can see that rvm did to my environment is to append ~/.rvm/bin onto my path.    I'm running "terminal" on OS X Mountain Lion.

edit: is there some way to tell bash to echo all processes launched from a shell command?

Comment: I think rvm overrides `cd` with a shell function. Try `which cd`

Comment: which cd gives /usr/bin/cd, also note that \cd gives the same behaviour so it's not been aliased

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605277/how-does-rvm-detect-when-youve-changed-directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cd` is overwritten by [RVM](https://rvm.io).

`.ruby-version` is a "standard" used by RVM/rbenv/chruby to allow you to switch to project specific Ruby.

You can fix this problem in two ways:

1. Make RVM install all missing rubies:

   ```
   echo rvm_install_on_use_flag=1 >> ~/.rvmrc
   ```
2. Make RVM install Ruby for current project:

   ```
   rvm use . --install
   ```

Comment: ok I finally found it -- rvm put a line in .bash_profile that installs itself into the environment, and cd is replaced as a function.